# About once every 24 games the random selection for my Black Jack game fails

Tags: python

About 2 months ago I started learning Python. So, I guess this might be obvious to many.

I made this Black Jack code, and it works more or less as I want it to work. Except from one bug thing which I cannot figure out what happens.

After getting my initial hand. If, I draw an "Ace of Spades" or an "Ace of Diamonds", the next card that I will draw will be same (either an "Ace of Spades" or an "Ace of Diamonds" depending on the previous), which is not supposed to happen due that the card should not be anymore in the deck, since it's already in my hand. By the end, there will still be 52 cards, but there will be 5 "Ace"s and a random other will be missing.

Sorry for the long post. This is my first Stack question and I'm still figure in out how to get the most out of it.

Here's my long and maybe not so optimal code:

```
import random


deck = {"Ace of Spades": 11, "2 of Spades": 2, "3 of Spades": 3, "4 of Spades": 4,
        "5 of Spades": 5, "6 of Spades": 6, "7 of Spades": 7, "8 of Spades": 8,
        "9 of Spades": 9, "10 of Spades": 10, "Jack of Spades": 10,
        "Queen of Spades": 10, "King of Spades": 10,
        "Ace of Hearts": 11, "2 of Hearts": 2, "3 of Hearts": 3, "4 of Hearts": 4,
        "5 of Hearts": 5, "6 of Hearts": 6, "7 of Hearts": 7, "8 of Hearts": 8,
        "9 of Hearts": 9, "10 of Hearts": 10, "Jack of Hearts": 10,
        "Queen of Hearts": 10, "King of Hearts": 10,
        "Ace of Clovers": 11, "2 of Clovers": 2, "3 of Clovers": 3, "4 of Clovers": 4,
        "5 of Clovers": 5, "6 of Clovers": 6, "7 of Clovers": 7, "8 of Clovers": 8,
        "9 of Clovers": 9, "10 of Clovers": 10, "Jack of Clovers": 10,
        "Queen of Clovers": 10, "King of Clovers": 10,
        "Ace of Diamonds": 11, "2 of Diamonds": 2, "3 of Diamonds": 3, "4 of Diamonds": 4,
        "5 of Diamonds": 5, "6 of Diamonds": 6, "7 of Diamonds": 7, "8 of Diamonds": 8,
        "9 of Diamonds": 9, "10 of Diamonds": 10, "Jack of Diamonds": 10,
        "Queen of Diamonds": 10, "King of Diamonds": 10}

###################################################################################################################
#####                                   DEFINING DEAL |BJ - SPECIFIC|                                         #####


def deal(deck: dict, value: int, cards_in_hand: list, show_list: list):
    """
    Deals a card for the Black Jack game and provides the added value of the card.
    :param deck: A Dictionary. Same for everybody.
    :param value: A score. Dependant on the player.
    :param cards_in_hand: A list. Dependant on the player.
    :return: Returns a random selected card, its int value and the updated deck without
    the drawn card
    """
    card = random.choice(list(deck))
    cards_in_hand.append(card)
    show_list.append(card)
    hand_value = deck.get(card) + value
    deck.pop(card)
    for card in cards_in_hand:
        if hand_value > 21 and "Ace" in card:
            hand_value = hand_value - 10
            cards_in_hand.remove(card)
    return card, hand_value

###################################################################################################################
#####                                                    RESET                                                #####


def reset(list1: list, list2: list, list3: list, list4: list,
          int1: int, int2: int, my_choice_: str, bot_choice_: str, deck_: dict):
    """
    Resets all the factors of the game to begin from scratch everytime you begin a new game.
    :param list1: Your hand related to value.
    :param list2: Your hand related to figures (or cards).
    :param list3: The bots hand related to value.
    :param list4: The bots related to figures (or cards).
    :param int1: The value or score of your cards.
    :param int2: The value or score of the bots hand.
    :param my_choice_: The decision to 'hit' or 'stand'.
    :param bot_choice_: The bots decision to 'hit' or 'stand'.
    :param deck_: The dictionary containing the full deck of cards.
    :return: Gives you back all the values as originals.
    """
    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    list3 = []
    list4 = []
    int1 = 0
    int2 = 0
    bot_choice_ = ""
    my_choice_ = ""
    deck_ = {"Ace of Spades": 11, "2 of Spades": 2, "3 of Spades": 3, "4 of Spades": 4,
             "5 of Spades": 5, "6 of Spades": 6, "7 of Spades": 7, "8 of Spades": 8,
             "9 of Spades": 9, "10 of Spades": 10, "Jack of Spades": 10,
             "Queen of Spades": 10, "King of Spades": 10,
             "Ace of Hearts": 11, "2 of Hearts": 2, "3 of Hearts": 3, "4 of Hearts": 4,
             "5 of Hearts": 5, "6 of Hearts": 6, "7 of Hearts": 7, "8 of Hearts": 8,
             "9 of Hearts": 9, "10 of Hearts": 10, "Jack of Hearts": 10,
             "Queen of Hearts": 10, "King of Hearts": 10,
             "Ace of Clovers": 11, "2 of Clovers": 2, "3 of Clovers": 3, "4 of Clovers": 4,
             "5 of Clovers": 5, "6 of Clovers": 6, "7 of Clovers": 7, "8 of Clovers": 8,
             "9 of Clovers": 9, "10 of Clovers": 10, "Jack of Clovers": 10,
             "Queen of Clovers": 10, "King of Clovers": 10,
             "Ace of Diamonds": 11, "2 of Diamonds": 2, "3 of Diamonds": 3, "4 of Diamonds": 4,
             "5 of Diamonds": 5, "6 of Diamonds": 6, "7 of Diamonds": 7, "8 of Diamonds": 8,
             "9 of Diamonds": 9, "10 of Diamonds": 10, "Jack of Diamonds": 10,
             "Queen of Diamonds": 10, "King of Diamonds": 10}
    return list1, list2, list3, list4, int1, int2, my_choice_, bot_choice_, deck_

###################################################################################################################
#####                                                 BOT PLAYER                                              #####


def bot(bot_score: int) -> str:
    """
    This bot is made to decide if s/he want to get another card from the dealer or not, depending on
    the value of his hand in relation to 21.
    :param bot_score: An int score of the sum value of cards
    :return: A decision of [Y/N] for 'Yes' or 'No' depending on card values.
    """
    if bot_score <= 16:
        bots_choice = "Y"
    else:
        bots_choice = "N"
    return bots_choice


###################################################################################################################
#####                                                    REFEREE                                              #####


def referee(bot_score: int, score: int, show_of_human: list, show_of_robot: list):
    """
    Compares the scores of the player and the bot and dictates a winner.
    :param bot_score: The int value of the sum of values of the cards of the bot.
    :param score: The int value of the sum of values of the cards of the player.
    :return: A decision of [Y/N] for 'Yes' or 'No' depending on card values.
    """
    referee_says = ""
    if bot_score >= 22 and score <= 21:
        referee_says = "DEALER: Ruben went over 21. You win!"
    elif score >= 22 and bot_score <= 21:
        referee_says = "DEALER: You went over 21. Ruben win!"
    elif bot_score and score >= 22:
        referee_says = "DEALER: You both went over 21. Nobody wins!"
    else:
        if bot_score == score:
            referee_says = "DEALER: It's a tie!"
        elif bot_score < score:
            referee_says = "DEALER: You win!"
        else:
            referee_says = "DEALER: Ruben win!"
    return "YOUR HAND: {1}\nRUBEN'S HAND: {0}\n\nWith a score of:\nYOU: {3}\nRUBEN: {2}\n" \
        .format(show_of_robot, show_of_human, bot_score, score) + referee_says


###################################################################################################################
#####                                             SCORES & HAND                                               #####


score = 0
bot_score = 0
my_cards = []
bots_cards = []
show_of_hand = []
show_of_bot = []
another_bot_card = ""
another_card = ""
hit = "Y"
stand = "N"
continue_playing = True



###################################################################################################################
#####                                              INTRO & GAME                                               #####


input("Press ENTER to play some Black Jack")
print()
ready_payer_one = input("DEALER: 'Are you ready to begin?'[Y/N]: ")
print("-" * 72)

while continue_playing:
    while ready_payer_one.upper() != "Y" or "N":
        if ready_payer_one.upper() == "Y":
            hand, score = deal(deck, score, my_cards, show_of_hand)
            hand2, score = deal(deck, score, my_cards, show_of_hand)
            bot_hand, bot_score = deal(deck, bot_score, bots_cards, show_of_bot)
            bot_hand2, bot_score = deal(deck, bot_score, bots_cards, show_of_bot)
            print("You got dealt a {} and a {}\n&".format(hand, hand2))
            print("Ruben, the robot, got dealt a {} and a face-down card".format(bot_hand))
            print("-" * 72)
            while another_bot_card.upper() != stand or another_card.upper() != stand:
                another_card = input("DEALER: Would you like another card?[Y/N]: ")
                another_bot_card = bot(bot_score)
                print("-" * 72)
                if another_card.upper() != hit or stand:
                    if another_card.upper() == hit:
                        hand, score = deal(deck, score, my_cards, show_of_hand)
                        print("You draw a {},".format(hand))
                    elif another_card.upper() == stand:
                        print("You stand,")
                    elif another_card.upper() != hit or stand:
                        another_card = input("DEALER: Dude, that's not a valid option. 'Y' to Hit or 'N' to Stand: ")
                        print("-" * 72)
                        if another_card.upper() == hit:
                            hand, score = deal(deck, score, my_cards, show_of_hand)
                            print("You draw a {}".format(hand))
                        elif another_card.upper() == stand:
                            print("You stand")

                if another_bot_card.upper() != stand:
                    bot_hand, bot_score = deal(deck, bot_score, bots_cards, show_of_bot)
                    print("Ruben draw a {}\n".format(bot_hand) + "-" * 72)
                else:
                    print("Ruben stands\n" + "-" * 72)

            final = referee(bot_score, score, show_of_hand, show_of_bot)
            print(final + "\n" + ("-" * 72))
            my_cards, bots_cards, show_of_hand, show_of_bot, score, bot_score, another_card, another_bot_card, deck = \
                reset(my_cards, bots_cards, show_of_hand, show_of_bot, score, bot_score, another_card, another_bot_card,
                      deck)
            break

        elif ready_payer_one.upper() == "N":
            print("DEALER: Thanks for the interest. Later!")
            break
        else:
            ready_payer_one = input("DEALER: That's not a valid choice. Please, choose 'Y' for Play or 'N' to Quit. ")
            print("-" * 72)
    again = input("DEALER: Type 'Iztaccihuatl' to PLAY AGAIN or 'N' to quit: ")
    print("DEALER: Haha trolled you. For next time, you can type anything to PLAY AGAIN...")
    print("-" * 72)
    if again.upper() == "N":
        print("MAURICIO: Thanks for playing!")
        continue_playing = False
```

Comment: Why is your `deal` *removing* cards from the hand?

Comment: I would suggest having a `list` of cards for the deck, instead of a dict. Then, `random.shuffle` the dect and `pop` cards from the deck to deal them. That is all.

Comment: This is too much code to expect people to review for a Stack Overflow question. If your question is about what happens when the cards are dealt, then you should show all the needed code - and *only* the needed code - to deal the cards.

Comment: I don't find any close reason appropriate. It's focused enough since it asks about one problem. It has enough clarity since it has all the details needed to define the problem. It provides the code and observed/desired result description. I think people are jumping onto it because the OP didn't trim down his code to the [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) required to reproduce the problem. And I can't fault them for that.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica So, in Black Jack an Ace is equivalent to either 11 or 1 depending on if the score goes over 21 or not. It might not be the best way, but, the solution that I found was removing the Ace after decreasing 10 points (to make change the original value of 11 to 1) so the function would loop multiple times under the same card named "Ace"... I hope that answers your question! And I appreciate your interest!

Comment: Hi @KarlKnechtel . I agree and I appreciate your feedback. The reason why I posted so much code was because I did not know where the error was. But thanks anyway, I'll keep it in mind for the future!

Comment: @Reti43 I appreciate you taking the time to review and giving me feedback! Good day!

Comment: Hi @zvone ! Yeah, I thought about that. But I wanted to have my cards as strings instead of just int values (e.g. "9 of hearts" instead of 9) and at some stage I would have needed to provide those values, right? I mean, maybe I could have done it with a list, but to be honest, I did not know how... Anyhow, thanks you very much for your time and feedback.

Comment: @MauricioGroso You could also have a `class Card`, which has suite, rank, value, description, whatever...

Comment: I will certainly try that @zvone . Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in your `deal` function. Here is the body of it again, just for reference:

```
card = random.choice(list(deck))
cards_in_hand.append(card)
show_list.append(card)
hand_value = deck.get(card) + value
deck.pop(card)
for card in cards_in_hand:
    if hand_value > 21 and "Ace" in card:
        hand_value = hand_value - 10
        cards_in_hand.remove(card)
return card, hand_value
```

The last line: `return card, hand_value`, presumably is supposed to return the randomly dealt card (which you were just dealt via `random.choice`), and the total value of your hand currently. However, the identifier `card` is being reused for your for-loop: `for card in cards_in_hand`. Effectively, the card you got from `random.choice(list(deck))` is now lost, and has been replaced with the temporary card used to iterate over your `cards_in_hand` collection. By the time you reach the return-statement, `card` will have taken on the value of whatever card happened to be last in your `cards_in_hand` list. Also, this bug can only happen when `cards_in_hand` is not empty, because if it is empty, the loop never takes place.

There are some other things you have overlooked, however - though they have very little to do with the issue you've described. First off, when the dealer asks me if I want another card, there's nothing stopping me from drawing more and more cards until `deck` becomes empty, at which point the line...:

`card = random.choice(list(deck))`

...in the `deal` function will raise an `IndexError`.

Also, some common beginner mistakes - here are some snippets:

```
while ready_payer_one.upper() != "Y" or "N":
```

---

```
if another_card.upper() != hit or stand:
```

---

```
elif another_card.upper() != hit or stand:
```

These snippets all commit the same mistake. Even though Python is a high-level language, and Python source code may sometimes read like an english sentence, these boolean expressions aren't being evaluated in the way you think they are. As long as `"N"` or `stand` are non-empty strings, they will be evaluated as being "truthy", and as you know, an `or` just needs one of its operands to be true for the entire expression to be true. In other words, you will always enter the bodies of these loops/if-statements.

Comment: So insightful, thanks! I originally did think about changing those reused values just for the sake of not generating confusion, but I never thought that they could have been the issue of the bug! I makes loads of sense. Still, I find it very weird that it only happens with "Ace of Diamonds" and "Ace of Spades" (at least as far as I have experienced). Anyhow,  I appreciate you taking the time to highlight this issue and the other things that I overlooked. Good day!

Answer (score 0):

If you add a line at the beginning of your program defining an array like this:
`used = [False] * 52 # checks whether the card you are picking has been drawn`

Then in your deal function, you can change `card = random.choice(list(deck))` to

```
choice = random.randint(0, 51)
while used[choice] is True:
    choice = random.randint(0, 51)
used[choice] = True
card = list(deck)[choice]
```

This should work because it checks if the card has already been drawn and only puts it in your hand if it hasn't.

Comment: This also seems like a very valid solution. I will also give it a go! Thanks!

Comment: No problem :) Happy to help